# UIButton created dynamically in UITableViewCell at Row Editing time not responding to touch event

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am displaying tableview from custom cell and its working fine. 
But the problem is that UiButton that is created inside tableCell not responding to selector.

I swipe the Row for Editing Then I create UIButton in  **titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath** .
That appears same time when Delete button, touching Delete button responds to **commitEditingStyle:** Then Delete Button and Add button Disappers. Again I swipe the Row then Add & Delete Button Appear If I Click on Add Button It always Responds to **canEditRowAtIndexPath** then **didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath**.

I can't figure out why it's not calling **btnMethod**. Please let me know how to make it that btnMethod can called from uibutton touchDown event.

***Here is My Code:***

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell11=[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[cell11.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+433];


    btn.hidden=YES;

    [btn removeFromSuperview];
}    
}


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell11=[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *btnAdd=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnAdd.frame=CGRectMake(8, 6, 80, 30);
[btnAdd setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnAdd.backgroundColor=[UIColor magentaColor];
btnAdd.titleLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
btnAdd.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
btnAdd.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
btnAdd.layer.cornerRadius=6.0;
btnAdd.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
btnAdd.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
btnAdd.tag=indexPath.row+433;
[btnAdd addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnAdd.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[cell11.contentView addSubview:btnAdd];
return @"Drop Me";
}
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView1 didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell11=[tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)[cell11.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+433];
btn.hidden=YES;
[btn removeFromSuperview];

}
-(void)btnMethod:(id)sender
{
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];

}
```

Comment: Your this method never gets called that is why button is never added. - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   it would be better to add the button in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Dear Button Added and it appears along with Delete button when cell swipe problem is its never accept touch while delete button do

Comment: ok let me check..i am implementing all of this.

Comment: I tried.. but i guess in delete mode only the Dlete button will work..so it is not possible..

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper Thanks a lot  for your Effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created sample application. Its worked fine for me using your above code.

Two suggestion from my side

1: use **[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:btnAdd];**

Second suggestion will be a worst case

2: Try with **GustureRecognizers**

Comment: Mr. Ramshad I added your code [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:btnAdd]; just below adding to Button to Subview in the willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath its not working.

Comment: Please let me know how do you call a method using btnAdd with my code?

Comment: GustureRecognizers was ur great Idea